# IsPrime() function getting None values

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, nonetype

Hi i created some code for an is_prime function however when i enter small values i get none instead of true/false can anyone explain to me why this is?

```
 def is_prime(n):
  if n <= 1:
     return False

    for i in range(2,n):
        if (n%i == 0):
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: The code you posted throws a syntax error.

Comment: You have an indentation error. The entire `for` loop should be back-intended.

Comment: Your problem is probably indentation. But with the indentation as you have given it, the code cannot even be run. If you're going to post Python code, please make an effort to reproduce your indentation accurately. If readers have to try and guess your actual indentation, they may miss problems or introduce new ones into the program.

Comment: Your for loop is running in the if scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indent your loop properly like this:
The first `if` and `for` should be in the same line.

```
def is_prime(n):
 if n <= 1:
    return False

 for i in range(2,n):
    if (n%i == 0):
        return False
 return True
```

Now it works properly,

```
In [652]: is_prime(5)
Out[652]: True

In [653]: is_prime(6)
Out[653]: False

In [654]: is_prime(7)
Out[654]: True
```